# SQL Ranking Statement for Access- Duplicates in Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

I have a simple Access table [Parts] that stores the data

```
Part#  CYTD_SALES    CUST_NUM
```

I need to rank the parts in terms of CYTD Sales (Current Year To Day Sales) for each `CUST_NUM` (Customer Number) separately

I am using the following statement:

Rank:

```
(SELECT Count (*)  
 FROM [Parts] as R 
 Where [CYTD Sales] > [Parts].[CYTD Sales] 
   And > CUST_NUM= [Parts].[CUST_NUM] ) + 1
```

I ran into situation when the same amount was spent for more than 1 part by same customer, so the ranking looks like this

```
1 2 4 4 5
```

instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there a way to write a statement that would not allow identical rankings for the same customer?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there no primary key in the [Parts] table?

Comment: No, this table is an output of another query. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have any field by which you can tell the rows apart, I know of no way to rank the rows uniquely. Perhaps you could have the previous query output some kind of unique identifier?

Comment: i think i could do a combo field that would be identical, each part is   only listed once for each customer, so a field that would contain "Part#&CUST_NUM" would be unique. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Since Part# field is unique for each customer, below is the statement that worked for me:

```
(SELECT Count (*)  
 FROM [Parts] as R 
 Where ([CYTD Sales] > [Parts].[CYTD Sales] Or 
([CYTD Sales]=[Parts].[CYTD Sales] And
 [Part#]> [Parts].[Part#]))
   And > CUST_NUM= [Parts].[CUST_NUM] ) + 1
```